# Dropping columns/variables based on count of missing in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a large dataset that looks like the one below. I would like to drop the variables (not the observations/rows) that have less 3 observations in the rows. In this case only variable `X1` needs to be dropped.

I apologise if I am asking something obvious, however, at this point I do not have a clue on how to proceed with this.

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| ID  |  X1 | X2  | X3  | X4  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  .  |  1  |  1  |  2  |    
|  2  |  .  |  2  |  2  |  3  |    
|  3  |  .  |  3  |  1  |  .  |   
|  4  |  1  |  .  |  3  |  1  |   
|  5  |  .  |  2  |  4  |  3  |   
|  6  |  2  |  3  |  .  |  .  |    
|total|  2  |  5  |  5  |  4  |   
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My interpretation is you want to drop variables that have at least 3 missing values.

You can use `nmissing`, from SSC (`ssc install nmissing`):

```
clear
set more off

input ///
x y z
. . 5
. 6 8
4 . 9
. . 1
5 . .
end

list

nmissing, min(3)
drop `r(varlist)'
```

If my interpretation is incorrect, check the `help` for `nmissing` and `npresent`. The syntax is flexible enough.

### Edit

A re-interpretation. You want to drop variables that don't have at least 3 non-missing values:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
ID    X1  X2   X3   X4  
1    .    1    1    2      
2    .    2    2    3      
3    .    3    1    .     
4    1    .    3    1     
5    .    2    4    3     
6    2    3    .    .   
end

list, sep(0)

npresent, min(3)
keep `r(varlist)'

describe
```